# How to produce a compact letter display for overlapping confidence intervals?

Tags: r

I'm trying to produce a compact letter display for displaying all pairwise comparisons for overlapping intervals. I've tried searching for a package that would already do this, but I can't seem to find one not rooted in doing statistical pairwise comparisons.

```
    trt <- paste("", letters[1:10], sep = "")
    upper <- seq(from = 2, to = 10, length.out = 10)
    lower <- seq(from = 0, to = 8, length.out = 10)
    new.df <- data.frame(trt, upper, lower)
```

Thus, I end up with this data frame:

```
    > new.df
       trt     upper     lower
    1    a  2.000000 0.0000000
    2    b  2.888889 0.8888889
    3    c  3.777778 1.7777778
    4    d  4.666667 2.6666667
    5    e  5.555556 3.5555556
    6    f  6.444444 4.4444444
    7    g  7.333333 5.3333333
    8    h  8.222222 6.2222222
    9    i  9.111111 7.1111111
    10   j 10.000000 8.0000000
```

Then to make all the unique combinations this is what I used:

```
    comparisons <- combn(unique(new.df$trt), 2)
```

Which I then convert into a data frame.

```
   comparisons <- as.data.frame(cbind(comparisons[1,], comparisons[2,]))

    > head(comparisons)
      V1 V2
    1  a  b
    2  a  c
    3  a  d
    4  a  e
    5  a  f
    6  a  g
```

Once I get to my list of comparisons I'm not entirely sure where to proceed.

Comment: Can you post an example of your dataframe with the `trt, upper, lower` objects?

Comment: DoctaZee, welcome to Stack Oveflow. It looks like `trt` is missing, otherwise thanks for including code in your question!

Comment: Thanks for looking and pointing out the errors in the original code. I've updated the question with the data frame as well as the head of the comparisons output.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem, since you start out with intervals and not individual data points, but may this summary helps: https://github.com/SchmidtPaul/CompactLetterDisplayExample#compact-letter-display-cld-in-r